# _.orderBy not sorting by column in Vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, lodash, laravel-8, columnsorting

In Vue2 I want to sort my array of quizzes by column when I select a column in the select. But the _.orderBy (lodash) doesn't sort when I change the select, it does adjust the sortDirection. The orderBy is executed when the sortDirection changes. I have no errors. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Tips are appreciated!

**vue-component**

```
<template>
    <div class="py-6">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto lg:px-8">
            <div class="mt-5 flex lg:mt-0">
                <span class="block w-1/5">
                    <input v-model="search" autocomplete="no"
                           class="ml-3 border border-gray-300 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm rounded-md"
                           placeholder="Zoek hier naar quizzen..."
                           type="text">
                </span>

                <span class="block">
                    <select v-model="sortProperty"
                            class="ml-6 block w-full py-2 px-4 border border-gray-300 bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                            name="sortBy">
                        <option value="name">Naam</option>
                        <option value="playdate">Speeldatum</option>
                    </select>
                </span>

                <span class="block">
                    <button
                        class="ml-9 inline-flex justify-center py-2 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-gray-500 focus:outline-none"
                        type="button" @click="sortDirection === 'asc' ? sortDirection = 'desc' : sortDirection = 'asc'">
                        <svg v-if="sortDirection === 'asc'" class="h-5 w-5 mr-3" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="M3 4h13M3 8h9m-9 4h6m4 0l4-4m0 0l4 4m-4-4v12" stroke-linecap="round"
                                  stroke-linejoin="round"
                                  stroke-width="2"/>
                        </svg>
                        <svg v-if="sortDirection === 'desc'" class="h-5 w-5 mr-3" fill="none" stroke="currentColor"
                             viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="M3 4h13M3 8h9m-9 4h9m5-4v12m0 0l-4-4m4 4l4-4" stroke-linecap="round"
                                  stroke-linejoin="round"
                                  stroke-width="2"/>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>

            <div v-for="quiz in filteredQuizzes" v-if="filteredQuizzes.length > 0"
                 class="bg-white rounded-lg shadow-sm duration-500 px-2 sm:px-6 md:px-2 py-4 my-6">
                <div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-3">
                    <div class="col-span-12 sm:col-start-3 sm:col-end-13 px-3 sm:px-0">
                        <div class="mt-2">
                            <a class="sm:text-sm md:text-md lg:text-lg text-gray-700 font-bold">
                                {{ quiz.name }}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from 'lodash';
import axios from "axios";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            search: '',

            sortProperty: 'name',
            sortDirection: 'asc',

            quizzes: [],
        }
    },

    computed: {
        filteredQuizzes() {
            let quizzes = this.quizzes.filter(quiz => quiz.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()))

            return _.orderBy(quizzes, this.sortProperty, this.sortDirection)
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.fetchQuizzes();
    },

    methods: {
        fetchQuizzes() {
            axios.get('/quizzes').then(({data}) => (this.quizzes = data));
        },
    },

    name: "Quizzes"
}
</script>
```

Comment: I believe this should work just fine. Make sure you have property `playdate` on your quiz objects (if they are same value, you wont see any change on select). Also try not to use `v-if` on same element as `v-for` and use `:key` together with v-for.

Answer (score 0):

### EDITED version

```js
Vue.component("QuizItem", {
  props: ["name", "otherVar"],
  template: `
    <div>
      Name: {{ name }}<br>
      Other var: {{ otherVar }}<br>
      <hr />
    </div>
  `
})
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      sortDirection: "asc",
      sortProperty: "name",
      quizzes: [{
          name: "Quiz 34",
          otherVar: "DEF",
        },
        {
          name: "Quiz 23",
          otherVar: "GHI",
        },
        {
          name: "Quiz 12",
          otherVar: "JKL",
        },
        {
          name: "Quiz 45",
          otherVar: "ABC",
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredQuizzes() {
      let quizzes = this.quizzes.filter(quiz => quiz.name
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(
          this.search.toLowerCase()
        ))
      quizzes = _.orderBy(
        quizzes, [this.sortProperty], [this.sortDirection]
      )
      return quizzes
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div
      class="container"
    >
      <div class="quizzes col">
        <h4>FULL LIST:</h4>
        <quiz-item
          v-for="quiz in quizzes"
          :key="quiz.name"
          v-bind="quiz"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="quizzes col">
        <h4>FILTERED LIST:</h4>
        <quiz-item
          v-for="quiz in filteredQuizzes"
          :key="quiz.name"
          v-bind="quiz"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="filters col">
        <h4>CONTROLS</h4>
        <div>
          <span>Settings:</span>
          {{ search }}, {{ sortProperty }}, {{ sortDirection }}
        </div>
        <hr>
        <label>
          Search:
          <input type="text" v-model="search" />
        </label>
        <label>
          Sort property:
          <select v-model="sortProperty">
            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="otherVar">Other var</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <label>
          Sort direction:
          <select v-model="sortDirection">
            <option value="asc">ASC</option>
            <option value="desc">DESC</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  width: 33%;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Try the snippet above - it works. The problem was with this line:

```
return _.orderBy(quizzes, this.sortProperty, this.sortDirection)

// this should be this:
return _.orderBy(quizzes, [this.sortProperty], [this.sortDirection])
```

The reason is that `_.orderBy()` accepts a list (array) of attribute names by which it's going to sort the array AND an other list that controls the sort direction (in the same order as the attribute names are). Both of these arguments are supposed to be `Array`s, even if you only set 1 attribute & 1 corresponding sorting direction.

Comment: From the link you posted:`Returns (Array): Returns the new sorted array.`

Comment: @Beyers you are right, I looked only at the example. But did you check it?

Comment: @muka.gergely thank you for your help, it just didn't fix the problem. In fact, sorting with sortDirection also don't work. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: @Beyers edited my answer (removed the incorrect parts & added a working snippet). I hope it still helps you.